# PageRenderer returning null object during unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-2.0, spock

I have been tasked with writing unit tests for an existing service.

The service uses groovyPageRenderer in multiple places but I am not able to get anything except null from the render method.

```
reportXml = groovyPageRenderer.render(template: templateName,  model: [summary:result?.summaryData,reportDate: reportDate ])

pdfRenderingService.render([document: XMLResource.load(new InputSource(new StringReader(reportXml))).document])

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
```

I know the code works so I must be doing something wrong while configuring the unit test. I am doing this to inject it into the service.

```
def groovyPageRenderer
groovyPageRenderer = Mock(PageRenderer)
service.groovyPageRenderer = groovyPageRenderer
```

What else am I missing in order to obtain a result from the render method?

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting the mock, which is a good start, but you have to tell the mock how to behave when it's being used. Right now, you haven't given the render method any behavior, so it's just returning `null`.

You have to setup some interactions in Spock, [as explained in the documentation](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html).

Example code:

```
groovyPageRenderer.render(_) >> "<some>xml</some>"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it didn't, because of the mismatch in arguments. Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing something like this to make it work.

```
groovyPageRenderer.metaClass.render = {Map param -> return "something"}
```